# Flutter web app: Load prefs for theme efficiently

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a dark/light theme toggle option on my web app. I'm using shared preferences to persist the theme selection. I'm trying to keep the main UI separate from all the theme related work. So I created a `loadPrefs()` in my theme provider:

```dart
loadPrefs() async {
    bool isDark = await ThemePreference().isDark();
    _mode = isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The problem is that since this is an async function, I can't call it in `MyApp`'s constructor so I seem forced to call it in the `main()`

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
  ThemeProvider themeProvider = new ThemeProvider();
  await themeProvider.loadPrefs(); //HERE
  runApp(MyApp(themeProvider: themeProvider));
}
```

This is really messy because now I have to pass down the theme provider to the widget and then onto the widget's state class. I feel like there has to be an easier way to do this.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final ThemeProvider themeProvider;
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.themeProvider}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState(themeProvider: themeProvider);
}

class _MyAppState extends State {
  ThemeProvider themeProvider;
  _MyAppState({required this.themeProvider});
...
```

Comment: you don't need to pass down to the widget's state class. can't you access theme in provider in state using `widget.themeProvider`?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. Still new to Dart and Flutter. Let me try that.

Comment: @TahaMalik Nope, didn't work. It says the `The getter 'themeProvider' isn't defined for the type 'StatefulWidget'.`

Comment: wait for my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create your state class as follows

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
```

Now you can access all variables in `MyApp` using `widget.themeProvider`

If you want to keep your state class `dynamic` then you must cast your widget as

```dart
(widget as MyApp).themeProvider
```

For better managing your providers you can use

[provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)
This package will help you to manage all of your providers easy and effectively
[Official talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I) Listen to this official state management talk

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I will still need to pass it from `main()` to the widget though right? There is no other way to load prefs in the widget?

Comment: It depends on use case to use case. Normally a splash screen is shown until the app has initialized.